# Regexp to check if parentheses are balanced

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

I am writing a regexp to check if the input string is a correct arithmetic expression. The problem is checking if there are enough opening and closing parentheses.

Expressions:

1. (1)
2. (((1)
3. ((1))))

I think lookahead and lookbehind are useful here but for now I could check only one kind. I'm using Java, if it matters.

Comment: This is not a regular language. You're going to need to create a parser, even if it's a very simple one.

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't use regular expression to do this. Instead you can iterate over the string character by character and keep track of the nesting level.

Initially the nesting is 0. When you see a `(` increase the nesting by 1, and when you see `)` decrease the nesting. The expression is correctly balanced if the final nesting is 0 and the nesting never goes below 0.

```
public static boolean checkParentheses(String s) {
    int nesting = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
            case '(':
                nesting++;
                break;
            case ')':
                nesting--;
                if (nesting < 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return nesting == 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works great. It doesn't detect `()` though, but since OP asked properly opening and closing parentheses that won't matter.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be using a parser to do this, not a regex. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns).

Comment: Just a note that an regexp with conditional constructs can do this (.NET or perl): http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2005/02/20/377025.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not just count the opening and closing parens like so?

```
String expression = "((1+x) - 3 * 4(6*9(12+1)(4+(2*3+(4-4)))))";

int open = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < open; x++){
   if(expression[x] == '(')
      open++;
   else if(expression[x] == ')')
      open--;
}
if (open != 0)
   // Not a valid expression
```

Of course this only checks that you have the right amount - someone could write '))3*4((' and it would be validated using this method.

Comment: Before the open--, check if open is 0. If it is then fail the check. That would fail for the expression '))3*4((' or '(a+b))-(3*4)'.