# regex for searching balanced parentheses

Tags: regex

is there a way to match open and close parentheses?
since i am working under bash, it seems that i cannot use local variables and recursive matching.

e.g.

```
(((((123))))) # shall be matched
((123)        # shall not.
```

edit:
the scenario is a little bit different bacause all the parentheses are consecutive

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns) by way of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918681/regexp-to-check-if-parentheses-are-balanced

Comment: since all parentheses are consecutive, i thought this may be a property i can make use of

Answer (score 0):

This is a stretch but if the parentheses are consecutive and the maximum number of them is small, you could do something like `^(?:[\(]{1}[^\(\)]*[\)]{1}|[\(]{2}[^\(\)]*[\)]{2}|[\(]{3}[^\(\)]*[\)]{3}|[\(]{4}[^\(\)]*[\)]{4})$`.